# Cakephp auth login problem?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In my database I have users table,and one record - user ,password for this is hashed with md5.

Problem is every time I try to login with right admin/pass I get bad user/pass login msg.

Here is my controller :

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Users';

    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow(array('*'));
    }



     function login() {
            //debug($this->data);
           if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in!');                
        }
    }

    function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
}
```

and from appControler

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    var $components = array('Auth', 'Session');

    function beforeFilter() {
        //debug($this->data);
        //Security::setHash('md5');
        $this->Auth->allow('admin_index', 'index', 'login', 'logout');
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index');
    }

}
```

login.ctp :

```
<div class="login">
    <?
    $session->flash('auth');
    echo $form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));
    echo $form->inputs(array('legend' => __('Login', true), 'username', 'password'));
    echo $form->end('Login');
    ?>
</div>
```

here are debug msg from app_controller

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [username] => admin
            [password] => pass
        )

)
```

and debug msg from users controller :

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [username] => admin
            [password] => 8e2665a3fe6983fa38464685ac4a3d9c93a3d301
  //this is not empty anymore but it is not same as in database
        )

)
```

here is sql code,that is good,but user pass hashed is wrong.

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`created` FROM `users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`username` = 'admin' AND `User`.`password` = '09b98f2308740bf305ce1e1097d02ded' LIMIT 1
```

What could be the problem?I'm new in cakephp.
Tnx in advance

Comment: forget the old post, you do not have to hash manually, if you stick with the defaults. why do you want to use md5? sha1 is the default (iirc) and more secure.

Comment: rewrote edit1 to be easier to use

Comment: @benjamin I edited again my answer,now it just send me again to same page(login).I'm new in cakephp,probably is some small fix

Comment: the second comment from @benjamin seems to be the solution: The debug output of the pass is 40 chars long (md5) while the db entry is 32 chars which is sha1

Comment: @harpax,Hi,probably that is the solution,but I'm not sure how to implement it.Can yoo tell me what to edit,to make this work?

Comment: @user303832: I changed the edit1! Hope it works now.

Comment: well, any easy way would be to copy your debug output to the db and to add future users by an User::add action (which uses the selected encryption and the salt set in the config of cake) .. this obviously is only working if you are about to set up a new app with an empty user table

Comment: new users will not be added to database,I copy output to db,and replace it with current pass,but still nothing happens when click login button,it send me again to login page

Comment: @user303832: you got my last comment?

Comment: @benjamin,yes,that fix problem,tnx you very much,you to harpax

Comment: @user303832: just one more little remark: forgetting to remove the $this->Auth->allow('*') before testing access rights can be annoying.

Comment: @benjamin one more question,I'm trying to connect auth component with table wp_users,but according to this http://book.cakephp.org/view/1251/Setting-Auth-Component-Variables it should be easy to choose another table,but now I get another errors Error: Database table acos for model Aco was not found.

Comment: @user303832: Attention, you are entering another realm here. AUTH is not equal to ACL component, yet they work well together. Please post another well-formed question (not a comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user303832,

you have to add the `login, logout` to your set of allowed actions via `$this->Auth->allow(` .

**Edit0:**
Another frequent point of failure is that the password confirmation field is omitted, causing the hash of the earlier password being hashed again and persisted in the database.
As the password is now double-hashed, a user can no longer log in. It is so common, that it has its own name (ninjahash) Ü.

**Edit1:**
My deep apologies: Please change your line back to:

```
$this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
```

and

```
$this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'login');
```

In addition, make sure that your database table is configured to take a char(40) as a password(@haprax: this is what the book suggests even for sha1).

Comment: tnx @benjamin for response,I edited my code in question,ok how to fix ninjahash :)))

Comment: I try this,but didn't help,it send me again to login page http://techpub.wordpress.com/2007/11/25/how-to-password-hashing-in-cakephp/

Answer (score 1):

Don't try use any other format of hashing because cakephp has not mention any particular format of hashing. According to me Cakephp convert it according to security.Salt value and decipher value that we change in cofig file of cakephp.

So, Solution is create a use after implementing auth component and then Cake php will create password in its own format and then try to login.